# Remove www and .html with with a single redirect

Tags: nginx, redirect

I'm having an issue where if a user types:

```
www.myurl.com/page.html
```

they are redirected first to

```
myurl.com/page.html
```

and then to

```
myurl.com/page
```

This is because I have the following in my conf file

```
    #remove www from url
    if ($host ~* ^www\.(.*)) {
        set $remove_www $1; 
        rewrite ^(.*)$ http://$remove_www$1 permanent;
    }

    location  /{

            # removes .html extension
            if ($request_uri ~ \.html($|\?)) {
                    rewrite ^(.+)\.html$ $1 permanent;
            }
    }
```

**My question**:

Is there a way to eliminate the the first redirect so that if a users types `www.mysite.com/page.html` they are redirected straight to `mysite.com/page`

Comment: Is your question not answered by [Everything you ever wanted to know about mod_rewrite rules but were afraid to ask](http://serverfault.com/questions/214512)? (Hint: nginx rewrite rules are very similar to Apache rewrite rules - It's just regular expressions: `$1` is the first thing in parentheses, `$2` is the second, `$3` the third... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need your `www.` rule to strip the `.html` if present. You also shouldn't need the `if` statement in the second rewrite:

```
#remove www from url
if ($host ~* ^www\.(.*)) {
    set $remove_www $1; 
    rewrite ^(.*?)(\.html)?$ http://$remove_www$1 permanent;
}

location / {
    rewrite ^(.+)\.html$ $1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: ...see and I was going to suggest a disgusting regex match to do the work -- this is somewhat cleaner.

Comment: @mgorven the .html rewrite will not accept something like this: `www.myulr.com/page.html?foo=bar`

Comment: Also, if I add www. to the url it append "?" if I remove it will I still be able to use query strings?

Comment: @jwerre Remove the `?$args` (I was getting confused with `try_files`).

Comment: will do. What is $args btw?

Comment: @jwerre First match also needs to be non-greedy (see my edit). `$args` are the query string parameters.